How to click Copy icon selecting by condition of their Name column
How do click the Copy icon, below I am sharing the HTML code.
Scenario - Click on Copy icon where Name = komal (below is the HTML Code)
Cypress code which I used to achieve this scenario - but with no luck.

After execution of this code, the following is the result


Please include text of the code and HTML instead of images.

It's because the first 10 rows do not contain the word "komal".
cy.get('td').contains('komal') only succeeds for the row that has that word but fails for all the rest.
So iterating is a bad strategy here, and totally unnecessary. You can just specify the row directly in the query
cy.get('table').first().within(() => {
  cy.get('tr').contains('komal')            // gives you <td>
    .parent('tr')
    .within(() => {
      cy.get('td').first().within(() => {
        cy.get('button').first().click()
      })
  })
})

Slightly better
cy.get('table').first().within(() => {
  cy.contains('tr', 'komal')                // gives you <tr>
    .within(() => {
      cy.get('td').first().within(() => {
        cy.get('button').first().click()
      })
  })
})

or using find instead of within/get (equivalent but shorter)
cy.get('table').first()
  .contains('tr', 'komal')
  .find('td').first()
  .find('button').first().click()

